# Bootstrap: how to remove the box shadow from the modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, css

how can I remove the box shadow from bootstrap's modal? I tried with the css below but no luck. Any ideas?

css,

```
.modal-dialog {
        box-shadow: none;
        -webkit-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-box-shadow: none;
        -moz-transition: none;
        -webkit-transition: none;
    }
```

bootstrap,

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-backdrop="false">
  <div class="modal-dialog custom-class">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        ...
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Your syntax is correct, probably css rule is not strong enough - did you tried to add !important ?

Comment: yes I did. but no luck at all.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

I did try this and seems to work

```
.modal-content{
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    -o-box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0);
    box-shadow: 0 5px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0);
}
```

a bootply [sample](http://www.bootply.com/112298)

Comment: what is `-0-box-shadow:`??

Comment: ohh that should be `-o-` for opera.

Comment: is there any way to remove box shadow from all bootstrap elements?

Answer (score 16):

Have no fear, there is a very simple solution to this.

You simply need to be more specific in your CSS selector and include `div`. The reason for this is that the style you are trying to override in the Bootstrap CSS was written `div.modal-dialog {...}`.

In CSS, `element.class` is more specific than `.class`, and the more specific tag will always take precedence.

So your solution is simply:

```
div.modal-content{
    -webkit-box-shadow: none;
    -moz-box-shadow: none;
    -o-box-shadow: none;
    box-shadow: none;
}
```

### [See the working example on bootply.](http://www.bootply.com/112308)

Comment: And add border:0px; when you only use .modal-content and want it to  completely blend into the background / backdrop (with the same color). This is perfect for creating fullscreen navigations.

Answer (score 1):

Below css code working for me.

```
.modal-backdrop.fade.show{
   display:none;
 }
```